# Invalid value in a list of an argument

Tags: c#, list, arguments

I have a two classes like this

```cs
class ClassA
{
    // Some properties
    public String PropertyA { get; set; }
}

class ClassB
{
    public List<ClassA> PropertyB { get; private set; }

    ClassB()
    {
        PropertyB = new List<ClassA>();
    }
}
```

And then somewhere else I have a method like this

```cs
public String MyMethod(ClassB argument)
{
    //do stuff with all the PropertyA values
}
```

I expect that from arguments no element in PropertyB have a null or empty PropertyA (will generate an invalid result), what kind of exception should I throw? ArgumentException?

EDIT: So I'll try to explain it with words: I have a method that has a parameter of type ClassB, ClassB has a list of ClassA and each ClassA has a property that is a string. I'm building up a query with this properties, so I believe is better it stops in here instead when the query is used.

Comment: Why do you need to throw an exception in this case? I would let the .NET framework throw the exception.

Comment: You mean if `arguments` is an array containing: `[someClassAInstance, null, anotherInstance]`, what should you throw because you don't want a `null` reference as one of the element values? EDIT: And/or if say `anotherInstance.PropertyA == null` is also invalid, and should throw an exception?

Comment: @Vraiment Based on your edit, I'd suggest you document the nested requirements in the method doc and perform a pre-validation check and throw an `ArgumentException` (or a custom exception which inherits from that), or move the checks to lower level calls (perhaps a `BuildQuery` which might eventually take the `PropertyA` string as an input parameter which would throw an `ArgumentNullException`) which means you would start building the query and throw an exception part-way through.

Answer (score 1):

In code I've seen/used/write, `ArgumentException` is thrown when something generic is wrong with the argument (a property is null, etc). If the argument itself is null, you would throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

However, I wouldn't normally do that if I wasn't writing a library/framework of some kind. Generally I let the framework do it's job.

Comment: Depending on what the method is meant to do, `InvalidOperationException` might also be appropriate.

Comment: +1 [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx) also suggest an `ArgumentException`: _"Throw an ArgumentException or a class derived from ArgumentException if invalid parameters are passed."_ I would also throw it since it's good practise to fail as soon as possible. Otherwise you could have side effects if the `NullReferenceException` comes "too late" or it results in invalid results (as OP has mentioned). http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147480/should-one-check-for-null-if-he-does-not-expect-null